# How to validate my form elements using reactjs?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, validation

I'm really sorry for this simple question but really my brain doesn't work right now, how can I make validation of my inputs by react?

This is my index.js

```
import React from 'react';
import './style.scss';

const MyComponent = () => (
    <div style={{margin:'auto', float:'none'}}>

        <table cellSpacing="0" cellPadding="0" style={{margin:'0 auto',marginBottom:'2rem'}}>
            <thead>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <span
    style={{
        height: '100px',
        width: '100px',
        backgroundColor: 'darkgrey',
        borderRadius: '50%',
        display: 'inline-block'
    }}/>
                </td>
                <td style={{color:'#2c4e88'}}>
                    <h1><p>swedavia</p></h1>
                    <h2><p>swedish airports</p></h2>
                </td>
            </tr>
            </thead>
        </table>


        <form>
            <div style={{color:'darkgrey',padding: '16px'}}>
                <label htmlFor="uname">Username</label>
                <input type="text" name="uname" required/>
                    <label htmlFor="psw">Password</label>
                    <input type="password" name="psw" required/>
                        <div style={{marginTop:'2rem'}}>
                            <button type="submit">ОТПРАВИТЬ</button>
                            <span style={{float: 'right',paddingTop: '16px'}}><a href="#">Forgot password?</a></span>
                        </div>
            </div>
        </form>

    </div>
);
export default MyComponent;
```

Help me please to create that validation.

I simply need to check if values are not null and to change color of input border to red if values is null!

Comment: https://reactjs.org/docs/forms.html
https://www.google.co.il/search?q=input+validation+react

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';

function MyComponent() {
  const initialState = {
    userName: '',
    password: '',
    error: ''
  }

  const [values, setValues] = useState(initialState);

  const handleInputChange = event => {
    const { name, value } = event.target;

    setValues({ ...values, [name]: value.trim() });
  };

  const handleSubmit = event => {
    event.preventDefault();

    if (values.userName.length === 0 || values.password.length === 0) {
      setValues({ ...values, error: "Please fill this field" });
    }
    else {
      setValues({ ...values, error: "" });
    }

    // Handle form submission
    console.log("formData", values);
  };

  return (
    //call handleInputChange on state change event
    //call handleSubmit on onSubmit event
    //display the div containing the error and apply the error class
    <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
      {values.error && <div>{values.error}</div>}

      <input type='text' name='userName' placeholder="User Name" value={values.userName || ''} onChange={handleInputChange} />
      <input type='password' name='password' placeholder="Password" value={values.password || ''} onChange={handleInputChange} />
      <button type="submit">Submit</button>
    </form>
  )
}

MyComponent.propTypes = {
  userName: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
  password: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
  error: PropTypes.string.isRequired
};

export default MyComponent;
```

Answer (score 4):

For this i guess it's better to create React.component to save state of the form into it and upon submit take the state and validate it's values. I recommend you to use some validation library like [joi-browser](https://github.com/jeffbski/joi-browser) or [validator](https://www.npmjs.com/package/validator)

Something like this

```
import React from 'react';
import './style.scss';

class MyComponent extends React.Component {
  // initial state
state = {
   username : { val: "", err : "" },
   // ... etc
}

handleInputChange (e)   {
  // your logic for input change
  // you can even including "pre-validation" in this step
  const val = e.target.value;
  this.setState({ username: { val, err: "" } })
}

handleSubmit = () => {
   const { username, password } = this.state
   // better to validate password and login with some library, this is just an example
   // you should reset value of input on error and 
   // add `err`..err should be handled in your template where it should be shown
   if ( !username.length ) this.setState({ username: { val: "", err: "Please fill this field" } })

   //...submit stuff

}

render = () => {
  return ( // your template )
}
```

}

Hope it helps :)